# Save view state data into database Error

Tags: asp.net

i have a problem when put in Response.Redirect

Example, the data only record for the first key in, for all the rest data no record in DB.
Secondly, the purpose i use Response.Redirect is to refresh the webpage, any idea to clear data after insert data into DB ?

kindly advise. thank you.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string stat = Request.QueryString["stat"];
        if (stat == "insert")
        {
            StatLabel.Text = "New Record have been Insert";
        }

    }





    private void BindGrid(int rowcount)
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataRow dr;

        dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Test1", typeof(String)));

        dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Test2", typeof(String)));

        dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Test3", typeof(String)));



        if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount + 1; i++)
            {

                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    dr = dt.NewRow();

                    dr[0] = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();



                }

            }

            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr[0] = TextBox1.Text;

            dr[1] = TextBox2.Text;

            dr[2] = TextBox3.Text;

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);



        }

        else
        {

            dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr[0] = TextBox1.Text;

            dr[1] = TextBox2.Text;

            dr[2] = TextBox3.Text;



            dt.Rows.Add(dr);



        }



        // If ViewState has a data then use the value as the DataSource

        if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
        {

            GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];

            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        else
        {

            // Bind GridView with the initial data assocaited in the DataTable

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;

            GridView1.DataBind();



        }

        // Store the DataTable in ViewState to retain the values

        ViewState["CurrentData"] = dt;



    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if the ViewState has a data assoiciated within it. If
        if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
            int count = dt.Rows.Count;
            BindGrid(count);
        }
        else
        {
            BindGrid(1);
        }
        TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
        TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;

        TextBox1.Focus();
        TextBox2.Focus();
        TextBox3.Focus();
    }



    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            string str1 = oItem.Cells[0].Text;
            string str2 = oItem.Cells[1].Text;
            string str3 = oItem.Cells[2].Text;
            insertData(str1, str2, str3);
        }
    }

    public void insertData(string str1,string str2,string str3)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
       string sql = "insert into test (test1,test2,test3) values ('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "')";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cmd.Parameters.Clear();
       con.Close();
       Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?stat=insert");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what about adding your code of `Page_Load` into `if(!IsPostBack) { } `  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saving into the database, you redirect right after each insert. Hence, none of the subsequent inserts are executed. I would move the redirect out of the loop. Maybe you can pass the number of records inserted in the query string as well.

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string str1 = oItem.Cells[0].Text;
        string str2 = oItem.Cells[1].Text;
        string str3 = oItem.Cells[2].Text;
        insertData(str1, str2, str3);
    }
    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?stat=insert");
}

public void insertData(string str1,string str2,string str3)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   string sql = "insert into test (test1,test2,test3) values ('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "')";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
   con.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code i have find

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string str1 = oItem.Cells[0].Text;
        string str2 = oItem.Cells[1].Text;
        string str3 = oItem.Cells[2].Text;
        insertData(str1, str2, str3);
    }
}

public void insertData(string str1,string str2,string str3)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   string sql = "insert into test (test1,test2,test3) values ('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "')";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
   con.Close();
   Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?stat=insert");
}
```

in this on **Button2_Click** in for loop after first time it will redirect page so now Your method will be like this

Replace this Method

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    foreach (GridViewRow oItem in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string str1 = oItem.Cells[0].Text;
        string str2 = oItem.Cells[1].Text;
        string str3 = oItem.Cells[2].Text;
        insertData(str1, str2, str3);
    }
   Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?stat=insert");
}

public void insertData(string str1,string str2,string str3)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
   string sql = "insert into test (test1,test2,test3) values ('" + str1 + "','" + str2 + "','" + str3 + "')";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmd.Parameters.Clear();
   con.Close();

}
```