# How to add delete, update or edit button in grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

May i know how to write in the delete, update or edit button in the griview  based on below code ?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="test1" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="test2" runat="server"/>
 <asp:DropDownList ID = "test3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" ></asp:DropDownList>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>
 <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
```

[Save view state data into database Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204379/save-view-state-data-into-database-error)

Answer (score 0):

see this article

**[article is about CRUD Operation in GridView in ASP.NET(Add/Update/Delete) Programmetrically](http://www.codegain.com/articles/aspnet/gridcontrols/crud-operation-in-gridview-in-asp-net-programmetrically.aspx)**

it explained step by step

Answer (score 0):

See the link below for the explanation:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/454165/How-to-edit-delete-records-in-gridview